# phpThumb cannot find ImageMagick / Imagick

Tags: imagemagick, phpthumb

I'm having a problem with [phpThumb](http://phpthumb.sourceforge.net). It says in the documentation that to get the best out  of it, use ImageMagick / Imagick.

I've got this installed on the Server (running Centos 5.1), and can run `convert --version` and get the right info back. I can also run `which convert` which returns `/usr/bin/convert`

However, phpThumb can't location the `convert` program - the demo's show that:

> (requires ImageMagick, this server is running "n/a" so it will not work)

Does anyone have any pointers on how to fix this?

Cheers,
   Matt

Answer (score 3):

ImageMagick changed the way it reports the version, and phpThumb no longer recognizes the version info.

From:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.3.7 06/04/09
>   Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
>   Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2008
>   ImageMagick Studio LLC

To:

> Version: ImageMagick 6.6.2-6
>   2010-12-02 Q16
>   http://www.imagemagick.org Copyright:
>   Copyright (C) 1999-2010 ImageMagick
>   Studio LLC

There are now DASHES in the version! This is a simple fix, open phpthumb.class.php
look for the line:

```
if (eregi('^Version: [^0-9]*([ 0-9\\.\\:Q/]+) (http|file)\:', $versionstring[1], $matches)) {
```

Simply add a dash '-' after the Q/ and it will work. New line:

```
if (eregi('^Version: [^0-9]*([ 0-9\\.\\:Q/-] (http|file)\:', $versionstring[1], $matches)) {
```

Comment: The new line is missing +) (I would have edited it myself, but it didn't let me make a two-character change).

Comment: In my case, I had to change that line to the following to make it work: `if (preg_match('#^Version: ImageMagick [^0-9]*([ 0-9\\.\\:Q/\\-]+) OpenMP (http|file)\:#i', $versionstring[1], $matches)) {`

Comment: If anyone is still having problems with this, my ImageMagick version was x64 so the regex needed the x as well, and I have changed it to '^Version: [^0-9]*([x 0-9\\.\\:Q/]+) (http|file)\:', but the latest version 1.7.13 has this issue sorted

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked phpinfo() to make sure imagick is installed?  If not, you will need to install it.

[ImageMagick Install Instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setup.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - yep, ImageMagick is installed and shows up in my phpinfo() through Apache, and through PHP on the command line.

Matt

Answer (score 0):

The problem with phpThumb is often not a `missing ImageMagick` problem, but a problem with access to the exec function, because `phpThumb` is using binaries (`convert`) to create thumbnails. Make sure You have seen this http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvekey.cgi?keyword=phpThumb and http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-1598